# How do i insert an array of input fields into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html, multidimensional-array

Presently i am trying to insert an array of checkbox, radio and text fields into my db, the array inserts when i select a single option from each checkbox group.
But when i select multiple options from different groups or leave a group empty the insertion gets jumbled up.That is values from group 4 can get inserted into row for group 1.
Here is my code

Html form.

```
while($row2=$coursefetch1->fetch()){
    $iid = $row2['id'];
    if($row2['type'] == 0){
        echo '

        <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$row2['id'].'">
        <div class="row" align="center">

        <b> '.$row2['question'].' </b><br>
        <input type="hidden" id="question" name="question[]" value="'.$row2['question'].'">

        <input type="hidden" id="test_id" name="test_id[]" value="'.$row2['test_id'].'">
        <input type="checkbox" id="yanswer" name="yanswer1[]" value="a"><span> '.$row2['a'].' </span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yanswer" name="yanswer2[]" value="b"><span> '.$row2['b'].' </span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yanswer" name="yanswer3[]" value="c"><span> '.$row2['c'].' </span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yanswer" name="yanswer4[]" value="d"><span> '.$row2['d'].' </span><br>


        </div>
        </div>

        ';
    }

    elseif($row2['type'] == 2){
        echo '

        <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$row2['id'].'">
        <div class="row" align="center">

        <b> '.$row2['question'].' </b><br>
        <input type="hidden" id="question" name="question[]" value="'.$row2['question'].'">

        <input type="hidden" id="test_id" name="test_id[]" value="'.$row2['test_id'].'">
        <input type="radio" style="background-color:red;" id="yanswer" name="yanswer[]" value="a"><span> '.$row2['a'].' </span><br>
        <input type="radio" style="background-color:red;" id="yanswer" name="yanswer[]" value="b"><span> '.$row2['b'].' </span><br>
        <input type="radio" style="background-color:red;" id="yanswer" name="yanswer[]" value="c"><span> '.$row2['c'].' </span><br>
        <input type="radio" id="yanswer" name="yanswer[]" value="d"><span> '.$row2['d'].' </span><br>


        </div>
        </div>

        ';
    }

    elseif($row2['type'] == 1){

        echo '

        <div class="tab-pane" id="'.$row2['id'].'">
        <div class="row" align="center">

        <b> '.$row2['question'].' </b><br>
        <input type="hidden" id="question" name="question[]" value="'.$row2['question'].'">

        <input type="hidden" id="test_id" name="test_id[]" value="'.$row2['test_id'].'">
        <input type="text" id="yanswer" name="yanswer1[]" value="">


        </div>
        </div>

        ';
    }

}
?>


PHP that processes the form

    <?php
    require "head.php";


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $question_array = $_POST['question'];
      $testid_array = $_POST['test_id'];
      $answer_array = $_POST['yanswer'];
      $i = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($question_array); $i++) {
        $question = $question_array[$i];
        $testid = $testid_array[$i];
        $answer = $answer_array[$i];

        $enterscore = $achilles->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_answer` (test_id,question,your_answer)
        VALUES (:t,:q,:a)");

        $enterscore->bindparam(':t',$testid);
        $enterscore->bindparam(':q',$question);
        $enterscore->bindparam(':a',$answer);
        $enterscore->execute();

      }
    }
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: ids must be unique in document.

Comment: did you check error logs?

Comment: I am trying to make sure the right selections are inserted in the right rows. even when selection is empty

Comment: Would really appreciate a sample code as i am new a this

Answer (score 0):

> But when i select multiple options from different groups or leave a group empty the insertion gets jumbled up.

That’s because only for *checked* checkboxes a value is submitted. So the unchecked ones do not generate an entry in your array, and since the array index is assigned automatically, due to `[]` at the end of the field name, you get a “garbled” data structure.

Specify the index for the array elements upfront: `name="foo[0]"`, `name="foo[1]"` etc. That way, you will get the checked checkbox values in their defined “positions”, so that you know which value belongs to which answer.

---

As someone mentioned in comments already, IDs *must* be unique within an HTML document - so you need to go and fix that as well. Depending on what you need those IDs for in the first place, you need to either make them include some sort of counter value as well ... or remove them, if they don’t serve any particular purpose.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code or edition to mine i would really appreciate that as i am stuck here

Comment: No, try yourself please. What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: How to handle the POST values based on their index finding it confusing to format my code properly